# How to find out which before_filters were called while processing Rails request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to do this without using logger or debugger?

I am working with a huge app which has many `before_filter`s and it is difficult to get a complete picture of what is happening just by reading sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that there is. On top of that, it may not be easy to tell in what order the filters will be applied, especially if you have nested controllers with filters defined at different levels of the hierarcy. I recommend some debug logging, and some integration tests to explore what happens in different circumstances.